# Use of backslash (\) character in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Recently i came across this macro for creating a singleton instance.

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc) // ARC Version

#define SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(classname)   \
\
+ (classname *)sharedInstance\
{\
static classname *shared##classname = nil;\
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;\
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{\
shared##classname = [[self alloc] init];\
});\
return shared##classname;\
}
```

Can some one tell me what is the use of backslash character in every line.What is the advantage it provides?

Also what is the use of ## character over here?

Comment: The `##` character is **token oncatenation**, see more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor . In short, it takes both arguments (string `shared` and the value of `classname`) and generates one string from them.

Answer (score 3):

It's *escapes* the newline at the end of each line and allows a complex macro, like this, to maintain readability.

C pre-processor macros have to be defined on a single line (i.e. terminated by newline), and therefore long macros are required to use a backslash to escape intermediate newlines.

As an aside, you'll see something similar in Makefiles.

Comment: Ah! Of course. I knew it meant you could continue on a new line but escaping the newline character is what it's doing. Obvious now when you put it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The `##` character is **token concatenation**, see more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor.

In short, it takes both arguments (string `shared` and the value of `classname`) and generates one string from them.

In this case you don't really need to use `##`, the same macro would work with the following:

```
#define SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(classname)   \
\
+ (classname *)sharedInstance {\
    static classname *singleton = nil;\
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;\        
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{\
       singleton = [[self alloc] init];\
    });\
    return singleton;\
}
```

It would actually work even without the `classname` parameter:

```
#define SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON   \
\
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {\
    static id singleton = nil;\
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;\        
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{\
       singleton = [[self alloc] init];\
    });\
    return singleton;\
}
```

Note that it's helpful to indent complex macros because it makes them much more readable.